# How to convert flutter TimeOfDay to DateTime?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a time picker that returns the TimeOfDay object. But I have to save that value in a database as an integer of milliseconds which obtained from DateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime time)`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This is not possible.
`TimeOfDay` holds *only* the hour and minute. While a `DateTime` also has day/month/year

If you want to convert it, you will need more information. Such as the current DateTime. And then merge the two into one final datetime.

```dart
TimeOfDay t;
final now = new DateTime.now();
return new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, t.hour, t.minute);
```

Comment: No, you would add hours and minutes to dateTime.now()

Comment: Be aware that if you pick a time after 12AM your new DateTime will still be the current date. For instance, if now is 18:00 and I pick 02:00, it won't be the upcoming DateTime, it will be the last one.

Comment: @DiegoGarcia Please remove or correct your comment, as it results in a different hour and minutes values than the original TimeOfDay, like the OP intended. Thanks!

Comment: @AlmogC Ok it indeed has a bug in that sample, the fix would be very simple if the dart DateTime had the today constructor but it didn't have so I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 20):

You can use DateTime extension

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime applied(TimeOfDay time) {
    return DateTime(year, month, day, time.hour, time.minute);
  }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

`final dateTime = yourDate.applied(yourTimeOfDayValue);`

and change your sdk version in pubspec.yaml to

```
environment:
 sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use entension like this and also can add some more extension methods in separate file like dateTime_extensions.dart to make your work easy for future projects as well

file: **dateTime_extensions.dart;**

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
DateTime setTimeOfDay(TimeOfDay time) {
    return DateTime(this.year, this.month, this.day, time.hour, time.minute);
  }

  DateTime setTime(
      {int hours = 0,
      int minutes = 0,
      int seconds = 0,
      int milliSeconds = 0,
      int microSeconds = 0}) {
    return DateTime(this.year, this.month, this.day, hours, minutes, seconds,
        milliSeconds, microSeconds);
  }

  DateTime clearTime() {
    return DateTime(this.year, this.month, this.day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

   ///..... add more methods/properties for your convenience 
}
```

use it like this

```
import 'package:your_app/dateTime_extensions.dart';

    date.clearTime(); //to clear timeSpan
    date.setTime(); //also be used to clear time if you don't provide any parameters
    date.setTime(hours: 16,minutes: 23,seconds: 24); // will set time to existing date eg. existing_date 16:23:24
    date.setTimeOfDay(TimeOfDay(hour: 16, minute: 59));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's just a tiny method to join a `DateTime` and a `HourOfDay`:

```dart
DateTime join(DateTime date, TimeOfDay time) {
  return new DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, time.hour, time.minute);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set an extension on the `TimeOfDay` class:

```dart
extension TOD on TimeOfDay {
  DateTime toDateTime() {
    return DateTime(1, 1, 1, hour, minute);
  }
}
```

then use it like this:

```dart
TimeOfDay timeOfDay = TimeOfDay.now();

DateTime dateTimeOfDay = timeOfDay.toDateTime();
```

if you define the extenson in another file and you have not imported it yet, if you are using `vsc` you can just type `timeOfDay.toDateTime();` then `ctrl + .` and `vsc` will suggest importing that file. if you're not using `vsc`, then I guess you have to import the file of the extension manually.